Fluentd 1.16.3 on windows: how to enrich certain log entries without filtering out the rest?
I need to add a custom field to all log entries that contain string "myapp.database - Statement returned". All other logs that do not contain this string, should not be discarded/filtered out.
I managed to add the custom field by applying grep, parser and record_transformer filters, but at the cost of all other logs being filtered out or the log entries containing string "myapp.database - Statement returned" being duplicated. Neither of these results is acceptable - as i said, the log entries containing the string should get the new field and the remaining log entries should not be filtered out.
Eventually i tried to apply label routing but it resulted in log entries being filtered out and custom field not being added at all. Below is my fluentd config where i tried to apply labels.
<source>
  @type tail
  path C:\dmskrnl.log
  pos_file C:\dmskrnl.log.pos
  tag dmskrnl.raw  
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</source>

<filter dmskrnl.raw>
  @type grep
  <regexp>
    key message
    pattern /myapp.database - Statement returned/
  </regexp>
  @label @ENRICH
</filter>
 
<label @ENRICH>
  <filter dmskrnl.raw>
    @type parser
    key_name message
    reserve_data true
    tag dmskrnl.enriched  
    <parse>
      @type regexp
      expression /myapp\.database - Statement returned (?<returned_bytes>\d+) bytes/
    </parse>
</filter>

<filter dmskrnl.enriched>
  @type record_transformer  
  <record>    
    returned_bytes ${record["returned_bytes"]}
  </record>
</filter>

<match dmskrnl.enriched>
  @type stdout
</match>
</label>
  
<match dmskrnl.raw>
  @type stdout
</match>


you can leverage ruby here (or even python, after adding the plugins. ruby is built-in) by enable_ruby true and do all sorts of string modifications with that
I'm going with a simplified example of how it works, and i hope it helps with your case; let's assume the following:

logs are in this format: {"message": "sometext"}
I want to add a new field named check with boolean values (true/false)
if the word yes exists in sometext, check=true, otherwise check=false

I write the following fluent.conf for it:
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/myapp.log
  pos_file /var/log/td-agent/myapp.log.pos
  tag myapp.logs
  format none
</source>

<filter myapp.logs>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  <record>
    check "#{record['message'].include?('yes') ? 'true' : 'false'}"
  </record>
</filter>

<match myapp.logs>
  @type stdout
  <format>
    @type json
  </format>
</match>

(notice the use of a ruby ternary operator to assign values to "check" field)
